# Slick carousel middle item enlarged but shrinks when another item is hovered over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slick.js

I have a carousel that displays 3 items by default. In my Photoshop mockup I have the middle item enlarged slightly. I can achieve this effect using the `slick-center` class which is always applied to the middle item but now i'm wondering if it's possible so when one of the other items is interacted (hovered) with that will then enlarge and the middle item will return to the normal (smaller) size?

Do you think this'll be possible within the plugin or would it required a custom bit of Javascript?

I did think I could reduce all the sizes when the entire carousel is hovered over and then enlarge the actually item that the mouse is over but that was a bit jumpy and wasn't very graceful.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/GGNEza

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slick-carousel').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 960,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '120px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '60px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '30px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```css
/* Band */

.band {
  background: red;
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  max-width: 1350px;
}

/* Resorts */

.resort {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  margin: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .15s;
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.resort img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-center {
  transform: scale(1.06);
  z-index: 10;
}

.test {
  padding: 30px 15px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="band">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="slick-carousel">
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with a simply jQuery script to target the `.slick-current` class when hovering over any other `slick-slide`'s and give it a custom class.

Once that's done, a simple set of CSS rules to adjust sizes based on class will fix it.

The additional jQuery will look like this:

```
$('.slick-slide').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.slick-current').addClass('small');
});
$('.slick-slide').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.slick-current').removeClass('small');
});
```

And the added CSS would look like this:

```
.slick-current.small {
    transform: scale(0.95);
}
.slick-slide:hover {
    transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

Here's a working example:

(*Your codepen is a tiny bit different, so I've forked it with a working example as well - [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xzqBEw)*)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.slick-carousel').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '0',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 960,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '120px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '60px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '30px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  $('.slick-slide').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.slick-current').addClass('small');
  });
  $('.slick-slide').mouseleave(function(){
    $('.slick-current').removeClass('small');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Band */

.band {
  background: red;
  padding: 60px 0 30px;
  width: 100%;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  max-width: 1350px;
}

/* Resorts */

.resort {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .30);
  margin: 30px 0;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all .15s;
  transform: scale(.95);
}

.resort img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.slick-center {
  transform: scale(1.06);
  z-index: 10;
}

.test {
  padding: 30px 15px 0;
}

.slick-current.small {
  transform: scale(1);
}
.slick-slide:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="band">
  <div class="wrap">

    <div class="slick-carousel">
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div class="resort">
          <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/460/300" alt="ALT TEXT" />
          <div class="test">
            <h4>Spain</h4>
            <h2>Ibiza</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn">Find Out More</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll give it a prober test this evening! I couldn't get the CodePen to work, it keeps refreshing/loading over and over again so I can't see the example - strange! As an aside, I noticed if you remove a couple of items so there's only 3 the middle item loses it's `slick-center` class and the left and right items have that class applied instead: https://codepen.io/moy/pen/MXoadM ...have I done something wrong is that a fault with the plugin?! Thanks again!

Comment: @user1406440 did you come right with this? If you did, please upvote and accept the answer, and if not, let me know so we can take it from there :)

Comment: Is something wrong with the JS? Just CodePen keeps refreshing over and over?

Comment: @user1406440 that's strange, opens up perfectly fine on my firefox and my chrome. What browser are you using? Can you try on another one?

Comment: Just Chrome on Mac. I'll check again later and on Firefox too. As an aside, can you see an issue where when there's only 3 items the `slick-center` class is added to the left and right images and not the middle item?? Very odd! Think it's an issue with the plugin rather than how I've implemented it though.

Comment: @user1406440 Oh yeah, that's definitely not a problem with how you set it up. The plugin actually doesn't initiate the sliding functionality if there are less-or-equal items in total than the slidestoshow property, as technically you can only slide if there are more items. That functionality tends to mess with the "center" class...

Comment: Oddly that issue only occurs in Chome on my home iMac but not on Macbook - very strange! As both browsers are up to date. Thanks for all the help, the solution works great! I think I'll probably amend the CSS so the left/right items aren't shrunk so when they're hovered over there's no gap :) Thanks again!!